# Xpath query for same level tags..?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file -

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <PubDetails>
       <Pub Name="ABC"/>
       <Year Y="1999"/>
    </PubDetails>
    <Book Subject="Computers">XPath 2.0</Book>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <PubDetails>
       <Pub Name="ABC"/>
       <Year Y="1999"/>
    </PubDetails>
    <Book Subject="Management">Financial Management</Book>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

I want to retrieve the `Subject` when `Y` is passes as parameter.

For Ex: If I pass 1999, then I should get Computers, Management as output.

What will be the XPath 1.0 query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that the parameter `year` contains the value.

```
//Book[PubDetails/Year/@Y = $year]/Book/@Subject
```

Comment: Dear Vincent- Thanks a lot... I was forget to write the last `Book` tag before `/@Subject`. Thanks a lot again :)